# Intermittently git push hangs over ssh to gitosis

Tags: git, intermittent

I have an intermittent problem pushing to my git (gitosis) repository. Most of the time it works fine but when it doesn't work the push hangs. It seems to have done the majority of what it wants to do:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 67, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 7.89 KiB, done.
Total 43 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

I've waited a good long while for this to complete but to no avail.

On the server I have 3 processes running that may be relevant:

```
 1774 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: git [priv]    
 1776 ?        S      0:00 sshd: git@notty     
 1777 ?        Ss     0:00 sh -c gitosis-serve myusername
```

I've tried with a wired connection and a wireless connection to my router but switching between the two has no effect. I can't establish whether it is a local problem or a server problem either.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: Does the remote repository have any hooks that do no complete? That would be the first place I would start.

Comment: When the push hangs, is it after a long time of inactivity?  How often is it hanging on you?

Comment: @devicenull - I generally do a pull before the push which completes okay and I can connect directly to the machine over ssh. It really is intermittent; no pattern to how often it hangs that I can discern.

Comment: @L0neRanger - There are no hooks set to be executable on that repository. Only the standard hook post-update hook on the gitosis-admin repository.